# Properly wire LED battery level indicator between battery and load

Tags: wiring

I'm trying to add an LED battery level indicator to a circuit between the 42-volt battery and a load.  bellow I have attached the link to info on the LED indicator. I'm just unsure of how to connect it to the load.

https://www.dhgate.com/product/round-housing-arc-line-led-digital-battery/385506247.html#cppd-1-5|null:103:r1964942355

[image: neat hand-drawn schematic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked at the link you've provided, scrolled half a page, found this:

[image: Helpful picture]

Just connect it as it says.

You'd want to connect the V+ to the battery's positive terminal, 3- to the battery's negative terminal.

You can then add a switch to switch both the load on and the indicator; you'd do it like shown on the first picture.

Just use a switch and wiring that can handle your load, and connect the load effectively between the R an 3- terminals. The switch would go as shown between the battery's positive and R terminals.

If you intend to switch a beefier load, just use the schematic from Picture 2, using a beefy enough relay to handle your load.

Comment: I don't need a switch.   I just need a nice fancy looking LED voltmeter.   would I just connect the load to pins R  and 4?

Comment: Yeah, just wire it as if there was a closed switch